# VBA error "Unable to get the Hex2Dec property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a code that copies certain cell values from a workbook to another workbook. The twist is that the information is in hexadecimal in one workbook and I need to convert the value in decimal when I copy it to the other workbook.

What is weird is that everything works perfectly and the code copies and then adds the value, converted in the workbook needed; all until it reaches the last row and that's where I get the error. (the error shows up at the line that has a comment added)

```
Debug.Print Now
varSheetA = varSheetA.Range(RangeA)
Debug.Print Now


i = 1
For rowN = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        Tst = Mid(wbkB.Worksheets("CopyFromHere").Cells(rowN + 1, 2).Value, 3, 6)
        Set Rng = wbkA.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(RangeA).Find(Tst)
        If Rng Is Nothing Then
            i = i + 1
            wbkA.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(wbkB.Worksheets("CopyFromHere").Cells(rowN + 1, 5).Value) 'error is here

        End If

Next
```

I need to mention that some of the values that are in hexadecimal are these (just to have an idea): `239`, `7E101`, `7FA3A`, `B38`

And the value that currently the program gives error is `B38`

I don't understand why this happens, as the code runs perfectly well until that value/last row. I don't know which one is the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the cell really contains B38 or is there a white space in the cell?

Comment: I checked and it doesn't contain any white space or anything else :(

Comment: Did you try like suggested in my answert to trim the value of the cell?

Comment: Yes, I tried that out now, and it seems like it worked. I don't know what was hidden there as I checked for spaces or anything else. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean the "cell" before like that

```
    wbkA.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 5).Value = _
WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Trim(wbkB.Worksheets("CopyFromHere").Cells(rowN + 1, 5).Value))
```